# get_entry_list method by SugarCRM Soap

Tags: c#, soap, sugarcrm

I tried to order an Account Module by the field name using `get_event_list` from SugarCRM SOAP.

```
link_name_to_fields_array[] linkedFields = null;
String[] fields = new String[1];
fields[0] = "name";

var result = sugarClient.get_entry_list(sessionId, "accounts", "", "", 0,
fields, null, 100, 0, false);
```

But, when I execute this part of the code, it doesn't work.

For the method:

```
get_entry_list (sessionId, module_name, query, order_by, offset, select_fields, link_name_to_fields_array, max_results, deleted, favorites);
```

I think the `order_by` is misspelled in the method, but I don't know what the correct syntax is.

Comment: Use this var result = sugarClient.get_entry_list(sessionId, "accounts", "", "", '0',
fields, array(
         ), 100, 0, false);

Answer (score 1):

get_entry_list

Definition

get_entry_list(session, module_name, query, order_by, offset, select_fields, link_name_to_fields_array, max_results, deleted, favorites)

[image]

[image]